# Dynamically Set Selected Options of Multi SelectPicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a selectpicker, and I know the syntax to set the selected options of it via javascript:

```
$('.mySelectPicker').selectpicker('val', ['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

I'm trying to build a string in a loop: each time the loop iterates, this gets added (some PHP):

```
options += '\'' + '<?= $name ?>' + '\', ';
```

Then, I try to set the selected options like this:

```
$('.mySelectPicker').selectpicker('val', [options]);
```

However, there is something wrong with the syntax where I put "options". I am getting an error that says "Unexpected string". I think I'm referencing the options variable incorrectly. (I set it correctly a bit earlier in the code as `var options = "";` )

Comment: Where are you trying to build the string?  Your second snippet has php in it, or something non-javascript.

Comment: If you are trying to dynamically add elements to an array, this is the wrong approach.  The typical approach is to create your array `var options = []`, then `options.push(newValue)`

Comment: I did this earlier - however, when I tried to set the values with the selectpicker, it would not accept the array I passed in to it.

Comment: $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['Mustard','Relish']);  <-- this is the syntax it is asking for

Comment: String is getting build fine, it is inside of a while loop. I output the string and it looks good.

Comment: Right, but that's javascript text.  Javascript gets parsed, so the element that is passed into the method when it is called is a real array.  Which is why I asked where this code is being generated.  Are you trying to generate the array on the client side in javascript, or are you building the javascript on the server side dynamically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188138/discussion-between-hani-honey-and-taplar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being syntactically like this:

```
var options = []; options.push('Mustard'); options.push('Relish'); $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', options);
```

User Taplar provided the answer. Thank you!